# Python string concatenation append variable to path what is the correct syntax missing closing quote error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to append a string value of a variable to end of a string.
I am getting a missing closing quote.

My Python snippet is:

```
from Utilities.HelperMethods import read_from_file

class DataCategoriesPage_TestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def test_00001_add_data_categories(self):
        project_name = read_from_file("project_name")
        administration_page.enter_location_for_export(r"\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Test Data\ClearCore\Exports\5\" + project_name)
```

What is the correct syntax?

The value of the variable project name is `"selenium_regression_project_09/04/2016"`

I would like to add this to the end of the string path `\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Test Data\ClearCore\Exports\5\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't end a raw string literal with a `\`, because a backslash can still be used to escape a quote. Quoting the [string literal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) (from the section on raw string literals):

> String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, *a raw string cannot end in a single backslash* (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).

This looks like a file path, so use `os.path.join()` to concatenate the file path parts:

```
import os.path

administration_page.enter_location_for_export(
    os.path.join(
        r"\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Test Data\ClearCore\Exports\5",
        project_name))
```

Note that the raw string no longer needs to end with a backslash now.

Comment: This is because the backslash is escaping the closing quotes

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Peters has given the correct answer for your problem (use `os.path.join`), but there *is* a solution to the problem of having a literal with lots of back-slashes (so you want to write it as a raw literal), that ends with a back slash.  The solution is to write most of it as a raw literal, but write the trailing back-slash as an ordinary (escaped) literal.  Python will concatenate two adjacent string literals into one.  So in your case, the literal would be written as:

```
    r"\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Test Data\ClearCore\Exports\5" "\\"
```

This could conceivably be useful to someone writing some other back-slash heavy code (e.g. regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't end a raw string with a backslash - that will escape the final quotation mark. (Bug?). Try:

```
r"\\STORAGE-1\Testing\Test Data\ClearCore\Exports\5" + "\\" + project_name
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a deliberate design decision.  It means you can embed a quote in the string by back-slash escaping it.